# Как правильно собрать проект angular-cli?

Tags: angularjs, angular4, angular-cli

Создал проект через ng new. Далее запустил ничего не изменяя, всё работает. Проробывал собрать его через ng build --prod, всё прошло успешно, появился папка dist c index.html и другими скриптами для работы angular. Открыл index.html в браузере, а там ничего нет, пустая страница, хоть в коде всё прописанно и подключено. Может я что-то делаю не правиль, просто я новичок в angular. Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте запусить `index.html` не просто в браузере, а через какой-нибуь веб-серве.

Answer (score 4):

для запуска в режиме разработчика:

```
ng serve
```

компиляция:

```
ng build --prod
```

компиляция AOT:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

если надо запустить на определенном порте/хосту:

```
ng serve --env=dev --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4200
```

Переходм из браузера на:

http://127.0.0.1:4200

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему требуется запустить ng serve - команда соберет проект, создаст на localhost:4200 локальный сервер и начнет отслеживание изменений исходного кода для пересборки в реальном времени. Вы пишите - все обновляется на лету.

Answer (score 0):

Команда `ng build --prod` собирает Ваш проект в папку dist или в любую другую папку которую Вы укажете в свойстве `"outDir": "dist",` файла angular-cli.json.
Проект будет собран с включенной AOT компиляцией, минификацией кода, а так же будут включены некоторые другие функции оптимизации ([подробнее](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod)).

В папке dist index.html будет минифицирован, откройте его и посмотрите есть ли там вообще что то, в самом файле, далее требуется содержимое папки dist расположить на Вашем локальном веб-сервере или на хостинге, как Вам удобнее, после этого проверьте как все работает.

Команда `ng serve` собирает проект, но так же располагает его на веб-сервере, соответственно весь функционал оптимизации отключен. Если я не путаю, то в данном случае использует `webpack-dev-server` встроенный в angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

После сборки build --prod в папке dist находится еще одна папка заходите в эту папку и все что там есть выкладываете на свой хостинг. Так запустится все ваше приложение.

А команда ng serve - это команда запуска не сборки build --prod. А команда непосредственно для разработки. Она не запускает то что находится в папке DIST. А запускает ваш проект на порту 4200.